# Adding iframe (google map) to jquery with php

Tags: jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

This code works, but I want to work with PHP, so I can control in wordpress settings.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery('document').ready(function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                var meps = '<iframe style="border: 0;" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2209.031679248075!2d22.554804516065!3d56.381033750830454!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x46ef7f4796620a77%3A0xb28151d9fd19376d!2sDariaus%20ir%20Gir%C4%97no%20g.%2C%20Lai%C5%BEuva%2089475!5e0!3m2!1sen!2slt!4v1629095714907!5m2!1sen!2slt" width="600" height="450" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>';
                jQuery("#mapas").append(meps);
            }, 8000);
        });
    </script>
```

And this code doesn't work, no clue what is the problem.

```
<?php $map = get_field('map','options') ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('document').ready(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            var meps = '<?php echo $map ?>';
            jQuery("#mapas").append(meps);
        }, 8000);
    });
</script>
```

The `$map` contains the iframe and prints out the map, but won't "stick" with jquery, why?

Comment: what does "stick" mean and does the $map contain exactly the same as var meps did in example 1? Any errors in console or network tab?

Comment: By "stick" I mean that Jquery meps doesn't want accept value I'm trying to give to it. Yes, meps gets same var and error in console: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the same code in your active theme's `footer.php` file after the `wp_footer()` function.

If that works then that means jquery is not loaded when you are executing this code.

Comment: I just tried that, the error I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`, so I suppose  meps don't get value.